# Why do images generated using gdal2tiles have black lines?

Tags: tile, gdal2tiles.py

I used a command to cut my large image of 9000 * 6000, but the generated image will have very thin black lines in the middle. Does anyone know the reason and is there any way to remove these black lines?

```
gdal2tiles.py -p raster -z 4-8 -w none world_map_all.png
```

[image]